# .Net Identity - Field from super class is not saved to DB

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to have more types of users with different fields in Identity. User has a Name, PIN and Employee has also Name, and Department.

I created an AppUser to store the common fields (e.g. Name), which is an IdentityUser

```
AppUser : IdentityUser {
   public String Name;
}
```

And I tried to derive my real users (User, Employee) from them.

```
User : AppUser{
   public String PIN; 
}

Employee: AppUser{
   public String Department;
}
```

Althought this does not seem to work, the Name field is not persisted to DB when I seed the DB.

Is this approach wrong? How else should I do this? What am I missing?

Comment: `public String Name { get; set; }`.

Comment: Oh my god you are a genius :D If you write this as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework generate DataBase column corresponding Property of a class not Field. So try like

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser {
   public String Name { get; set; }
   public String PIN { get; set; }
}
```